# Image moves top to bottom and bottom to top continuously when button clicked

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an image and one button, when I clicked button the image is moved top to bottom and bottom to top continuously until I am click the stop button but when I click start button it move only bottom to top or top to bottom,its not moves continuously both sides.

my code is:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

RelativeLayout rl_footer;
ImageView iv_header;
boolean isBottom = true;
Button btn1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
    iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
    Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
            iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0); 
            //rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
            if (isBottom) {
                SlideToAbove();
                isBottom = false;

            } else {
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.download);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0,50);
                //rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
                SlideToDown();
                isBottom = true;
            }

        }
    });

}

public void SlideToAbove() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}

public void SlideToDown() {
    Animation slide = null;
    slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

    slide.setDuration(400);
    slide.setFillAfter(true);
    slide.setFillEnabled(true);
    rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

    slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            rl_footer.clearAnimation();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
            lp.setMargins(0, rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

        }

    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

   }
```

xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/graphics" >

 <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="70dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/download" />

  </RelativeLayout>
  <Button
 android:id="@+id/button1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_footer"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:text="start" />

<Button
 android:id="@+id/button2"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_footer"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:text="stop" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you start both the animations on click of the Button besides putting the `if..`loop? As you have kept a single `ImageView` in your layout you can not run the two animations on single image at a time.

Comment: Make sure you clearly and briefly describe your question first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out below code its working fine for your both animation and it moves image continuously from bottom to top and top to bottom. And will stop animation as you click on stop button.

I have done some relevant changes which you can verify with your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout rl_footer;
    ImageView iv_header;
    boolean isBottom = true;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rl_footer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_footer);
        iv_header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_up_arrow);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button buttonstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        buttonstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rl_footer.clearAnimation();
                rl_footer.removeAllViews();
            }
        });
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                // rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
                // if (isBottom) {
                SlideToAbove();
                // isBottom = false;

                // } else {
                // iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
                // iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0,50);
                // rl_footer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
                // SlideToDown();
                // isBottom = true;
                // }

            }
        });
    }

    public void SlideToAbove() {
        Animation slide = null;
        slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -5.0f);

        slide.setDuration(400);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setFillEnabled(true);
        rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

        slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

//              rl_footer.clearAnimation();

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
                // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 50);
                SlideToDown();
            }

        });

    }

    public void SlideToDown() {
        Animation slide = null;
        slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 5.2f);

        slide.setDuration(400);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setFillEnabled(true);
        rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

        slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

//              rl_footer.clearAnimation();

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        rl_footer.getWidth(), rl_footer.getHeight());
                lp.setMargins(0, rl_footer.getWidth(), 0, 0);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);
                iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);
                iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                SlideToAbove();

            }

        });

    }

}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_footer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="84dp"
        android:text="stop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the attribute `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` with the 2nd button and place it below the button you have put at top. check it if this solves your problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="start" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_up_arrow"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:src="your drawable" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/button1" // Change here
    android:text="stop" />
```

Comment: thank u for u r reply button is not my problem,my problem is  moves top to bottom and bottom to top continuously when button clicked.please check the java code

Comment: thank u for u r reply,image moves top to bottom and bottom to top continuously  when i click the start button and xml code is not a matter i can manage

Comment: on one click?? its happening?

Comment: yes but i have to click explicitly to move from top to bottom frequently.so my target is for single click image will move continuously until i am click stop button

Comment: kindlythanks for ur response  please once execute my code u can understand clearly

Comment: @user3202568 Checkout my answer i have made your code working.

Comment: thank very much friend for u reply.every thing ok but small change that is when click the stop button image is gone but my requirement is it has to wait at same position until i am click start button am much as iwant