# Animation with three images in android

Tags: android, animation, imageview, android-framelayout

I want Three images A,B,C one over the other, some portion of each image visible so that we can click images. At start there should be image A on top, B in middle and C at bottom. After few seconds it should animate and B should come on top, C in middle and A at bottom and so on... Clicking on any of the image should come to front. Please help me with this.

Comment: Try this - Hope this answer or link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226481/image-moves-top-to-bottom-and-bottom-to-top-continuously-when-button-clicked

Comment: in android there is a method called view.bringToFront(); using this also to atchive this.

Comment: I am having this approach that I take 3 imageViews in a Framelayout.Then I have no idea for Animation. Could you please suggest any animation link for the feature I require?